# Some problems with input functions and or logic

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I am having a simple problem with some input and if statements. I am using a function from this page and my modifications aren't working. This is my code:

```
def correct(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(raw_input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a number, please!")
            continue

        if (value != 1) or (value != 2):
                print("Enter a value of either 1 or 2, please!")
                continue
        else:
            break
        return value
```

The problem seems to be at the if statement. The intended behavior is to reject either inputs that aren't 1 or 2. However, it is rejecting all inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a common pitfall. You want to use `and` not `or` in your `if` statement. All numbers are not `1` or `2`. So you would want to change your code from `if (value != 1) or (value != 2):` to `if (value != 1) and (value != 2):`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this test:

```
if (value != 1) or (value != 2):
    ...
```

Apparently, it's `True` for any `value`, includung `1` and `2`. You could use `in`:

```
if value not in [1, 2]:
   ...
```

Also, the `return` statement in the function is never reached because it's indented to be part of the `while` loop and the loop is eventually terminated by `break`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
if value not in [1,2]:
    ...
```